# Python redirects form action

Tags: python, action, mechanize, redirect, http-status-code-302

I am working with mechanize and python 2.7 to send a request to a page with a form, GET data this time

```
<form method='get' action='/470711262846118652822405241081316835027/new2'>
<textarea name='name' rows='5' style='width:100%'></textarea>
<br>
<table summary='' style='width:100%'>
<tr>
<td align='right' valign='top'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

when I

```
try:
    request = Request(url,data,header)
    response = urlopen(request)
    html = response.read()
    return html
except IOError, e:
    print "*Cant open {0}{1}{2}".format(fg(2), url,attr(0))
    print "*Reason:{0}".format(e.reason)
    return None
```

The url I use in request is www.foo.com/new?name=bar but the action is new2 and this action redirects me to another page and I can't handle this. 
When I do all this things manually in the browser I can see the 302 code from the redirection using inspect element.

Header, cookies, data and everything is good, because I get the 200 https code and I can read the page, but not the redirection

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mechanize well, but it looks like you have not set `set_handle_redirect`, so the 302 status code is not being processed. 
See http://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser_api.html?highlight=handle#mechanize.Browser.set_handle_redirect

If you have not set this, you manually have to check for HTTP status 302 and read the `location` header to find the redirection target URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem here is I can'f find anywhere the 302 code with python, but i can do it manually in the "inspect element" from the browser. I already set the handle_redirect but nothing happens. The response is sending me again to the same page.

Comment: I do not know your requirements, but have you considered using Requests from Kenneth Reitz? A breeze to learn and very transparent on handling redirects? Tried several packages when starting with Python, but after requests I never looked back :-) http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Yes, I already tried it. I'm trying everything in multiple ways.